How to perform multiple operations on a JSON column based on differents conditions in postgreSQL?
I have a column "properties" of type jsonb in postgreSQL and I would like to modify the values of the different keys based on the values of other columns of my table.
However, I don't understand how to perform several operations on the same jsonb based on different conditions that are not linked between each other.
For example, I would like to update the "product" key of the column "properties" to "false" if the column "product" of my table is null and to update the "reference" key to "false" if the column "reference" of my table is null.
Here's an example of the content of what I have in the "properties" column.
{
    "product" : "true"  
    "reference": "true"
}

I tried to perform the operations one at a time but it seems not be the good way to do it because I have a lot columns to update.
Moreover I tried to search for nested queries but doesn't fit exactly what I need.

"I tried to perform the operations one at a time" - can you show us the SQL you used to do that?
